# GraphAPI not finding business page...but I can find it manually in Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I am looking for "Ellie's 50's Diner"

When I type it into the search bar in FB, or paste it, FB finds it just fine. Using the `graphAPI` I did this:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Ellies50sDiner
```

or

```
http://graph.facebook.com/search?q=Ellie's 50's Diner
```

It finds nothing.

Can someone please help me understand how to form this URL correctly?

Comment: how about pasting the code in C# that you are using where you can use Query Params vis aspnet code

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't you, it's what you are searching for.

If you look at Ellie's page on Facebook, http://www.facebook.com/pages/Ellies-50s-Diner/142627479109699, the numbers after the page show that the owner hasn't claimed a username.

In my experience, if a page owner hasn't claimed a username, they aren't a "real" page, and don't show up in search.